# Bootstrap Date field is not working in IE browser

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

Bootstrap Date calendar field is not working in IE browser so how it will work on Internet Explorer browser please help me .

Comment: Can you show the code that doesn't work and in which version of IE doesn't it work?

Comment: <input type="date" style="height: 40px;" class="form-control" required="required"    id="bdate" name="bdate" value="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"   placeholder="Enter Date Of Birth">

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#bdate').datepicker();
});
</script>

Comment: IE version 10 and 11